# Access - Count same value in multiple tables with one query

Tags: ms-access, count, ms-access-2010

I have gotten several different security reports that I am trying to work with. I would like to count how many times a particular IP address appears in 2 different tables.

I'd like it to look something like this:

IP Address Table1 Table2

xxx.xxx.xxx 12 13

I've seen a lot of people asking to count separate values in different tables, but not the same value in different tables, so I'm a little confused.

I created my initial count of just one table, by using the built-in query designer by using the join and count features; but, if I try multiple joins, the number goes really weird and I don't know what's happening. Access spit out this SQL when I tried with one table:

```
SELECT [Dell Printers by IP].Address, Count([Apache 12-24].[Vulnerability Title]) AS [CountOfVulnerability Title]
FROM [Apache 12-24] INNER JOIN [Dell Printers by IP] ON [Apache 12-24].[Asset IP Address] = [Dell Printers by IP].Address
GROUP BY [Dell Printers by IP].Address;
```

Also, how easy is it to scale to more tables than just 2?

Comment: Have to ask why are there 2 tables? Do they have the same structure?

Comment: They're the same structure. One is just an older report, for example.

Comment: Then I don't understand why 2 tables, instead of 1 with another field for a category value. Then a CROSSTAB query could generate the described output. Tables and queries have a limit of 255 fields. So that is your scale limit.

Comment: They're the same structure but have different data. One is an older vulnerability report and one is a newer report. So I can track variance, patterns, etc.

Comment: Well, if you are satisfied with structure, then go with. But you mentioned possibility of more than 2 tables. This sounds warning bells in my head. I still don't understand why you split records to separate tables when 1 table with filter criteria could probably provide same data output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how your tables are related in the database, I would suggest using a correlated subquery:

```sql
select 
  [ip addresses].[ip address],
  (select count(*) from table1 where table1.[ip address] = [ip addresses].[ip address]) as t1,
  (select count(*) from table2 where table2.[ip address] = [ip addresses].[ip address]) as t2
from
  [ip addresses]
```

Assumes that your IP Addresses to be queried reside in a table called `ip addresses`.

Comment: That's kinda why I included a sample of what Access did with the single count. I'm creating a new query. With your code, I don't have to do any sort of join?

Comment: @howradisit As soon as you introduce joins you risk omitting records contained in one table but not the other (MS Access SQL does not have an `OUTER JOIN`); hence why I suggest the correlated subquery, such that the two tables are entirely distinct.

Comment: Thanks. That actually worked. And it's scalable, which is nifty.